# WordPress JSON API for mobile app. Response time very slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, wordpress, caching

i am currently using the [WordPress JSPON API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) plugin to feed my mobile iOS application with content from the blog.

However the response time to load some posts inside the app is very slow and i am now looking to find a way to optimize it.

I read about the [transients API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) but not sure if this will be the right thing for it and also i don´t know how exactly to integrate this with the JSON API Plugin to get better response times?

Currently to fetch 10 Posts takes about 7-8 seconds (remote)

```
 strURl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@get_recent_posts/?page=%i&dev=1",mainURL,page];
```

Locally this takes about less then a second.

Now can anyone tell me what to do here?

Comment: Have you checked your server logs to see how long the request is taking? I would recommend figuring out if it is network latency or WordPress first, then digging in deeper.

Comment: Thanks, network latency isn´t the problem.

Comment: Add an `error_log("start:" . time())` statement at the start and end of your function so you can see how much time it is spending executing it.

Comment: Caching/transients/etc may help, but you need to know the specific code that is slow first.

Comment: Though it's unlikely that it would make that much of a different remote vs local - the code execution times should be similar unless the hosting environment is different?

Comment: @romu how did you end up solving your problem?